# Is it possible to share UI Image with assigned link to FB?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-social-plugins, fbsdk

My app suggests user to share some results(reached inside the App) which collected to one UIImage (so this is not the image with known URL)

I want sharer also to share the link to some page(lets say "stackoverflow.com")

The problem is that if i add a link to controller, sharing controller does not show UIImage(showing page logo or a snippet),  otherwise correctly shows UIImage without link.

I use SLComposeViewController, but this is not obligatory.
Due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755679/facebook-share-button-in-navigation-bar-appears-inactive) I can't use FBSDKShareButton (if it's needed). FBSDKSharingDialog does not accept UIImages

code:

```
//image : UIImage    
let fbShareController: SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
fbShareController.addImage(image) 
fbShareController.addURL(NSURL(string: "www.stackoverflow.com"))

self.presentViewController(fbShareController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Is this new Facebook policy, or my issue?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is not possible with `SLComposeViewController`.

The reason is when you add an image it is attached to the post as image. When you add an URL though, SLComposeViewController's private implementation ( or Facebook's backend services ..hard to say which one) takes over and it parses the URL and provides an appropriate image (if one is available as a result of parsing the URL contents) to complement the link.
The post then becomes a post with URL which doesn't show locally attached images.

Comment: Well, thank you, but what can I do? Native Share Dialog will not help because I don't know the URL of my Image (and saving images somewhere seems a big headache)

Comment: It's simply not possible. If you want an image together with public URL, you have to host the image publicly, have its URL and provide an URL to the Controller.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It sounds normal, that in simple html you can't publish an image without Url. It is interesting, how my UIImage is passed to Facebook feed. If it is saved somewhere , what is the problem with adding my link to final post ? Url comes to FB when UIImage is saved, and adding a href tag is not a big deal.

Comment: That is a different problem. Afaik around the time of FB app version etc 30 FB changed its policy and it is no posibble to set any initial text for the dialog. The method is there but it doesnt work for facebook social aharing although it still works for twitter. I think it has something to do with protecting users from rogue apps passing in unndesirable content tu user's posts.

Comment: Also if you provide both url and image via the api the image is ignored and the url takes precedence which is a design/business decision on fb part.

Comment: That is what I suspected, but could not find. In Facebook documentation there is only a note, that custom images linked to AppStore or GooglePlay will be changed to some info about Target App. But nothing more. Doubting "is that me" or "is that FB" I felt bad for several days.